# TextBox autoscroll on adding text from code behind in wp8.1 rt

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am adding some text from code behind on tapping button but it is not auto scrolling.

Sample is below.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="TestTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="test" MaxHeight="60" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Button Content="Add text" Tapped="Button_Tapped"  /> 
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
 int i = 0;
 private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     TestTextBox.Text = TestTextBox.Text + " newtest " + i++;
     TestTextBox.SelectionStart = TestTextBox.Text.Length;
 }
```

Any direction to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean it is not auto scrolling ?

Comment: It's not scrolling means that when I press button to add text from code behind, it keeps appending text to textbox. But the textbox vertical scroll doesnt go to latest text. I cannot see the latest text in textbox when added from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this:

xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinWidth">51</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinHeight">34</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">2.5</Thickness>
    <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">20.26</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlThemePadding">7,0.8,8,0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlMarginThemeThickness">0,9.5,0,9.5</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness">0,0,0,4.8</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeOpacity">0.8</x:Double>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled" Loaded="ContentElement_Loaded"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="TestTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="test" MaxHeight="60" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"/>
    <Button Content="Add text" Tapped="Button_Tapped"  /> 
</StackPanel>
```

In xaml, fetch scrollviewer of textbox and change its vertical position.

CodeBehind:

```
    int i = 0;
    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestTextBox.Text = TestTextBox.Text + " newtest " + i++;
        TestTextBox.SelectionStart = TestTextBox.Text.Length;
        sv.ChangeView(null, sv.ScrollableHeight, null);
    }

    ScrollViewer sv; 
    private void ContentElement_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
    }
```

This solved the issue, but is it ok to use?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) property and set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility`

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="TestTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="test"  MaxHeight="60" TextWrapping="Wrap">            
    </TextBox>        
    <Button Content="Add text" Tapped="Button_Tapped"  />
</StackPanel>
```

codebehind

```
 int i = 0;
 private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    TestTextBox.Text = TestTextBox.Text + " newtest " + i++ + Environment.NewLine;
    TestTextBox.SelectionStart = TestTextBox.Text.Length;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tested this code even this doesn't resolve my issue.Plus I cannot add newline as I want text to be added in continuation.